# db2 luw reorg table

Tags: db2, reorganize

My doubt concerns how to determine exactly when it is necessary to reorg a table.

My application executes the following select:

```
SELECT TABNAME FROM SYSIBMADM.ADMINTABINFO WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'DB2ADMIN' AND REORG_PENDING = 'Y'
```

Right now I have found the following article of IBM:

[IBM documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-do-i-determine-how-many-reorg-recommended-operations-have-been-done-table)

They suggest to use:

```
SELECT TABSCHEMA, TABNAME, NUM_REORG_REC_ALTERS, REORG_PENDING FROM SYSIBMADM.ADMINTABINFO where tabname='TAB1'
```

So from 'SYSIBMADM.ADMINTABINFO' they consider also the column 'NUM_REORG_REC_ALTERS'

In the articale is reported:

*Certain "ALTER TABLE" statements are considered "REORG-recommended" operations. After 3 of such operations your table will be forced into a reorg pending state. Limited access to a table that has had "REORG-recommended" operations is permitted, thus, you may need to know how many have been done so far. After three such operations no access to the table is allowed until a REORG has been performed.*

I've found also the documentation of column [NUM_REORG_REC_ALTERS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2oc?topic=aracp-admin-get-tab-info-retrieve-table-size-state-information)

However, it is still not clear to me whether to have a list of the tables to be reorganised is sufficient:

```
SELECT TABNAME FROM SYSIBMADM.ADMINTABINFO WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'DB2ADMIN' AND REORG_PENDING = 'Y'
```

Or is preferable:

```
SELECT TABNAME FROM SYSIBMADM.ADMINTABINFO WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'DB2ADMIN' AND (REORG_PENDING = 'Y' OR NUM_REORG_REC_ALTERS > 0)
```

What is your opinion on this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The necessity of a table reorg must be dictated by this table access pattern.
`REORG_PENDING = 'Y' AND NUM_REORG_REC_ALTERS < 3` means that your table is  readonly accessible + a number of other statements allowed on this table which are mentioned in the doc.
`REORG_PENDING = 'Y' AND NUM_REORG_REC_ALTERS = 3` means that your table is readonly accessible, and no other alters are allowed on this table.

You must decide on your own, if you need to take any action with such a particular table in its state depending on this table access pattern.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks.
So will never happens the following conditions?
REORG_PENDING = 'N' AND NUM_REORG_REC_ALTERS < 3 
or
REORG_PENDING = 'N' AND NUM_REORG_REC_ALTERS = 3

If true to have the full list is enough:
SELECT TABNAME FROM SYSIBMADM.ADMINTABINFO WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'DB2ADMIN' AND REORG_PENDING = 'Y'

Because when NUM_REORG_REC_ALTERS > 0, then REORG_PENDING is always = 'Y'

Correct?

Comment: `REORG_PENDING = 'N' AND NUM_REORG_REC_ALTERS < 3` is `true` for whatever table in the normal state, since it has `REORG_PENDING = 'N' AND NUM_REORG_REC_ALTERS = 0`. `REORG_PENDING = 'N' AND NUM_REORG_REC_ALTERS = 3` is `false` always. Again, tables with `NUM_REORG_REC_ALTERS = 3` and `NUM_REORG_REC_ALTERS BETWEEN IN (1, 2)` have different restrictions. "to have the full list" - of tables in what state exactly?

Comment: I need the full list of tables to reorg.
In short I need to know that when NUM_REORG_REC_ALTERS > 0, then REORG_PENDING is always = 'Y'?
For example: will never happens that a table has NUM_REORG_REC_ALTERS = 1 and 
REORG_PENDING = 'N'
Correct?
If true I will have to consider only the field REORG_PENDING = 'Y' and not the field NUM_REORG_REC_ALTERS.
Thanks again

Comment: If you need a list of tables, which need to be brought back to a normal state after at least one reorg-recommended commands, then yes, just use `REORG_PENDING = 'Y'`.